# Desbloquear campo ao selecionar Chekbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

**Cenário:** Possuo uma tabela onde o funcionário pode visualizar os dados que a empresa possui do mesmo. Necessito de uma opção para o funcionário relatar divergências em seus dados cadastrais.
Ao clicar no botão, abrirá uma tela onde conterá todos os dados (inicialmente bloqueados), e ao funcionário selecionar um dado (por meio de um checkbox), o campo ficará habilitado para inserção de dados.

Estou com dúvida de como elaborar esta tabela.

Tenho ela funcionando, porém estou usando uma função para cada campo, porém tenho muitos campos, e gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer, que não necessite usar tantos campos no script.

Segue o Fiddle para melhor compreensão.
[Exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/x7anhxu6/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Cpf">
<input type="text" id="CpfT">

<input type="checkbox" id="RG">
<input type="text" id="RGT">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('Cpf').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('CpfT').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('RG').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('RGT').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Comment: Pode ser com jquery?

Comment: @chambelix pode sim

Comment: fiquei sem perceber qual foi a solução que lhe resolveu a questão.Pode me esclarecer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode definir uma classe para os checkboxes e então definir o onclick de todos eles em uma única função.

No exemplo abaixo eu usei um atributo customizado ("data-id") para associar os checkboxes aos inputs. Você pode definir quantos elementos forem necessários sem a necessidade de adicionar nada ao javascript.

Para que funcione basta que o atributo `data-id` do `checkbox` seja igual ao `data-id` do input.

```js
var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');

function cbClick() {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[data-id="' + this.getAttribute('data-id') + '"]:not([type="checkbox"])');
    input.disabled = !this.checked;
}

for(var i in cbs) {
    cbs[i].onclick = cbClick;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="cpf">
<input type="text" data-id="cpf" disabled>
    
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="RG" data-id="rg">
<input type="text" data-id="rg" disabled>
    
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="teste">
<input type="text" data-id="teste" disabled>
```

Comment: As duas respostas me atenderam perfeitamente, poderiam dizer em termo de perfomace, se algo muda?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Em questão de performance, teoricamente, a minha solução seria um pouco mais lenta. Mas não acredito que  vá fazer diferença a menos que você tenha milhares de elementos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar uma função no evento `onchange` do `checkbox` passando o `this`.
Considerando que sempre haverá um `input` depois do `checkbox`, então na função é só usar o `nextElementSibling`<sup>[[1]](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp)</sup> para pegar o próximo elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
function muda(el) {
  el.nextElementSibling.disabled = !el.checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Cpf" onchange="muda(this);">
<input type="text" id="CpfT" disabled="true">

<input type="checkbox" id="RG" onchange="muda(this);">
<input type="text" id="RGT" disabled="true">
```

Caso você achar que, no futuro, poderá haver mudança na estrutura do HTML, a solução acima não deverá funcionar. Nesse caso podes passar também o id do `input` na função:

```js
function muda(el, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = !el.checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Cpf" onchange="muda(this, 'CpfT');">
<input type="text" id="CpfT" disabled="true">

<input type="checkbox" id="RG" onchange="muda(this, 'RGT');">
<input type="text" id="RGT" disabled="true">
```

Comment: As duas respostas me atenderam perfeitamente, poderiam dizer em termo de perfomace, se algo muda?

Comment: Se tiver, deve ser mínima. A não ser que você colocar váaaarios campos. Aí acho que o for da resposta do André pode ser mais lento, pois ele irá percorrer todos os campos.

Comment: @Earendul O único problema que vejo na sua solução é que por usar `nextElementSibling` ele não vai poder mudar a estrutura do HTML. Se em uma tabela o `checkbox` estiver em um `td` e o `input` em outro, isso não vai funcionar.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Exato. Por isso coloquei lá "Considerando...". Usei essa técnica para deixar o código mais simples. Com certeza sua resposta é mais robusta quanto à estrutura HTML, ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi o que pretende é habilitar ou desabilitar um conjunto de elementos agrupados e quer utilizar uma checkbox para o fazer... então tem esta forma em `JQUERY` que lhe preparei. 
Coloque um container que no exemplo coloquei o `<label>` mas você escolhe. Define um estado inicial no exemplo defino `disabled` e `readonly` dependendo do que utilizo.

```
<label> 
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxContent(this)"/> 
    <button  disabled>exemplo</button>
    <input type="text" value="exemplo" readonly>
</label>
```

Desta forma a `checkbox` vai servir para habilitar ou desabilitar todos os elementos que estão dentro do container `<label>`, excepto o próprio elemento checkbox.

Para então realizar a magia...com `javascript` ou `JQUERY` que é o caso do exemplo que coloco você utiliza:

```
function checkboxContent(element) {
   var cb = $(element);
   var value = cb.is(':checked');
   cb.parent().children('input, button').each(function () {
       var t = $(this);
       if (t.attr('type') !== 'checkbox') {
           t.attr('readonly', !value);
           t.attr('disabled', !value);
       }
   });
}
```

Pode ser melhorado, por exemplo com um plugin JQUERY que evita a utilização do `onclick` no html que é menos elegante. Esta no entanto é já uma forma funcional, pronta a utilizar :)